# Groupby and filter dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, regression

```
df  fruit   year price  vol  signifiance
0   apple   2010  1      5 
1   apple   2011  2      4   
2   apple   2012  3      3   
3   apple   2013  3      3   
4   apple   2014  3      3   
5   apple   2015  3      3   important
...
47   banana  2010  1      4
```

If a fruit-year is important, I want to regress price on vol using data 5 years before and after that important fruit-year.

e.g. for apple, regress price on vol from 2010 to 2020 .

I tried:

```
df = df.groupby('significance')
Y = df['price']
X = df['vol']
model = sm.OLS(Y,X)
```

Comment: There is always only one or zero `important` per `fruit` groups?

Comment: There can be multiple "important" years within a fruit but they don't overlap.

Comment: Are years consecutive per groups?

Comment: Some fruits have different starting years, but it's annual data for each fruit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

g = df.groupby('fruit')
for group in g.groups.keys():
    df1 = g.get_group(group)
    #filter years with important rows
    years = df1.loc[df1['signifiance'].eq('important'), 'year']
    print (years)
    
    #for each year get get years between 5 previous and 5 next years
    for year in years:
        data = df1[df1['year'].between(year - 5, year + 5)]
        print (data)

        #if returned data processing
        if not data.empty:
            X = data['vol'] 
            Y = data['price']
            model = sm.OLS(Y, X)
            results = model.fit()
            print (results.summary())
```

EDIT:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm


def f(df1):
    m1 = df1['signifiance'].eq('important')
    years = df1.loc[m1, 'year']
    print (years)
    
    #for each year get get years between 5 previous and 5 next years
    for year in years:
        mask = df1['year'].between(year - 5, year + 5) & df1['vol'].notna() & df1['price'].notna()
        data = df1[mask] 
        # print (data)

        #if returned data processing
        if not data.empty:
            X = data['vol'] 
            Y = data['price']
            model = sm.OLS(Y, X)
            results = model.fit()
            # print (results.params)
            df1.loc[mask & m1, 'new'] = results.params.iat[0]
    return df1


df = df.groupby('fruit').apply(f)
print (df)
```

Comment: "exog contains inf or nans". Shouldn't the data.empty take care of that?

Comment: @asd - hmmm, one idea is change `df1[df1['year'].between(year - 5, year + 5)]` to `df1[df1['year'].between(year - 5, year + 5) & df1['vol'].notna() & df1['price'].notna()]`

Comment: Last thing, sorry. Is there a quick way to add the vol coefficient as a new column, next to the signficance column in df?

Comment: @asd - Do you think `print (results.params)` ?

Comment: Yep ```results.params.vol ```worked worked but ideally wanted to add it to the original df

Comment: Thank you! Would you mind explaining how ```df1.loc[mask & m1, 'new']``` works?

Comment: @asd - it means is chained 2 masks - `mask` and `m1` by `&` for bitwise `AND` for filtering column `new`. In another words filtered all conditions from this masks

Comment: In boolean terms is it like: "if a row in both series, mask and m1, have a True, then..."